# phoneauthprovider's oncodesent not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have been trying to solve this problem but I can't seem to know what's wrong. I have a button that when clicked calls PhoneAuthProvider which has 4 options: OnVerifiicationCompleted, OnVerificationFailed, OnCodeSent, and onCodeAutoRetrieval. The problem is that oncodesent is being called but the code that I put in there doesn't work, not even a debug log. All I get is an SMS message showing a verification code. And when I set a string value to onCodeSent's verificationID, the string is value: null. Here's my code:

```
sendLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popSound.start();

            if (greenCheck.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                //send link

                // we will finish this activity and send the link to the number
                // an option to resend code to the number: it will be provided at the link
                // in this format: resend code to (XXX)-XxX-XXXX
                String number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
                phoneNumber.setText("");
                sendLink.setEnabled(false);

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        number,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        MobileNumberActivity.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                                // verificationID never gets assigned s and it is null. log.d isn't on logcat
                                verificationID = s;
                                Log.d("testing", "onCodeSent: " + verificationID);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                                super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
                            }
                        }
                );


                Intent i = new Intent(MobileNumberActivity.this, VerificationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            } else if (phoneNumber.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MobileNumberActivity.this, "Please enter a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MobileNumberActivity.this, "Please enter a valid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you calling `super.onCodeSent(...)`? The [sample in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks) doesn't do this, so you might want to see if removing that call fixes the problem.

Comment: I just commented out and still the same issue. Could it be a glitch? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: How do you know your `onCodeSent` is being called? Because with only the logging statement remaining in there, I don't see how the method gets invoked without the logging also being caled.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think it's being called because I get an SMS message that gives me a verification code and also on the logcat it shows: 03-30 13:41:57.089 6228-32467/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onCodeSent... but it isn't executing the code I have in the method, like assigning my field variable to its string verificationID.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally found the answer after trial and error. I don't know quite why this works but my guess is because since I am creating an instance of PhoneAuthProvider, it only works in oncreate. I had mine in oncreate but it was surrounded by a setOnClickListener as you see in the code above. So what worked for me is to start an intent to direct it to my verification activity, which in its oncreate method I created an instance of PhoneAuthProvider just by itself and it worked.

First activity:

```
sendLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popSound.start();

            if (greenCheck.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                //send link

                number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
                phoneNumber.setText("");
                sendLink.setEnabled(false);



                Intent i = new Intent(MobileNumberActivity.this, VerificationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);



                finish();
            } else if (phoneNumber.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MobileNumberActivity.this, "Please enter a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MobileNumberActivity.this, "Please enter a valid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            Log.d("COmpleted", "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.w("failed", "onVerificationFailed", e);

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // ...
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // ...
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            Log.d("codesent", "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationID = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

            // ...
        }
    };


    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            MobileNumberActivity.number,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);
}
```